# Can I say "go in the direction the voice came from"?

Tags: grammaticality

Let's say

When I walked in the park, I heard a cat was meowing.
So I tried to look for that cat.

I'd like to explain this situation like

"I went in the direction the voice came from."

Does it make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense. You could also say 'I followed the sound of the voice'.

Comment: Thank you so much again, Kate Bunting! 
At first I was going to go with "I went in the direction of the voice."
Does it sound unnatural?

Comment: @Yuki - that is fine, and good because it is short.

Comment: Michael Harvey, thank you so much!
It's all clear now, thanks to you guys.